# how to create Vaadin handler for when the push has failed?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I workink with [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) now. It is support [push-server](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html) technology.

I need to create a handler when the push is not successful (connection to server lost). I found how do it for Ajax technology [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962285/how-can-i-force-vaadin-client-engine-to-retry-sending-requests-to-the-server), but for push I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer of one expert of Vaadin:

> That is a relatively advanced matter.
>
> Vaadin is a server-side framework, merely a big server-side extension
>   to client-side GWT framework. Therefore the following is not possible
>   to do in Vaadin, but only in GWT whose minimum knowledge is then
>   required.
>
> The official Vaadin TouchKit addon (Vaadin GUI for mobile)
>   [already includes](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Offline%20mode%20for%20TouchKit%204%20mobile%20apps) such an offline functionality, though it does
>   not use cookies as storage ([source code on GitHub](https://github.com/vaadin/touchkit/tree/master/vaadin-touchkit-agpl/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/touchkit/gwt/client/offlinemode)).

Anton Nikonienkov